# how to keep softkeyboard's mode, when set value of input by js

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, android-keypad

the first, sorry for my poor English.

on html page on android device:

1) user click on a input, the os popup softkeyboard

2) user chooses number mode

3) set value of input when the still focus on input(means the softkeyboard is existing)

4) *  because set value of the input, so the softkeyboard mode change to default (QWERTY)

how to prevent this behavior?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I may have your request backwards, but to make the keyboard pop up in number mode, use

```
<input type="number">
```

Note that this works in html5 capable browsers.

Comment: the value contains non-number chars. like spaces. so, i can't use number type.